# Android listSelector vs setting the list item background

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView whose choice mode is set to single-choice. I want the selected item, if any, to be highlighted (i.e., to have a background of a different color from the rest of the items).

I had been relying on setting the list selector in order to achieve this. However, I found that, when my ListView is on a tab (i.e., contained within a TabHost), then if I switch to a different tab and back again to the tab containing the ListView, the selected item is no longer highlighted in the UI, even though `getCheckedItemPosition()` on the ListView still returns the same value as before.

This makes me think that I have misunderstood the purpose of the list selector.

On the other hand, I find that if I change the layout resource used for my list items to one whose background color varies according to whether the `android:state_activated` flag is set, I can achieve my desired highlighting behavior, and the selection highlight is retained across tab switches.

So I guess my question is, what is the purpose of the list selector if not to indicate the selected item? Is it not for "persistent" highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

1. android:state_selected attribute in selector xml
2. View.setSelected()